# How to open Video file in Fullscreen when login

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, video, login

I have a Video (avi) file that i want to open in fullscreen automaticly when i login.

I thought about login script or even small software for this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

for example:

1. Install VLC (http://www.videolan.org/)
2. Create a .bat file with following content:

if you want aslo to loop the video add "--loop" to the script

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" --loop --fullscreen
>   C:\path\to\your.avi

for example:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" --loop --fullscreen
>   C:\Users\user\Downloads\bird.avi

3. In Windows7 hit Start -> All programs -> Right click Startup -> Open all users or go directly to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
4. Copy the new .bat file there

Your video should now start automatically

Comment: Great! I will try to see it later if it is working. By the way, how do i configure it to play in loop?

Comment: I have updated the answer